# PHP Header Redirect with Values from a POST, Curl Problems

Tags: php, curl

I know there are other answers to this, and I've looked at them and still having trouble.  Basically have click tracking software and want to pass several different IDs from a form submit.

This is what I've tried:

```
 if(isset($_POST['pid']))     
 $pid   = $_POST['pid']; 
 $Curl_Session = curl_init('http://myurl/db/click.php?c=8&key=XXX');
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "pid=$pid");
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_exec ($Curl_Session);
 curl_close ($Curl_Session);
 header("Location:http://myurl/cgi-bin/thanks.php");
```

but without the last header line (I want it to redirect to the curl url).  Found it at this site: http://www.askapache.com/php/sending-post-form-data-php-curl.html#Sending_POST_data_placing_response_variable

When I run the above it goes to a 404 page?  I tried moving c=8&key= to the curlopt_postfields, but that resulted in the tracking software not working.

What am I doing wrong, and is this the way I should go about doing this?

Ultimately what I want to do is this:

```
header("Location:http://myurl/db/click.php?c=8&key=XXX&pid=" . $_POST['pid']);
```

but this ofc does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: 404 means the URL is wrong.

Comment: No, 404 means that the "Page was not FOUND" but not the "URL is WRONG" which would have a different meaning

Comment: what happens when you type the redirect url directly into your browser?

Comment: you mean the url I want?  it works.  I know what 404 means :D.

Comment: OK, kind of figured something out.  The place I'm sending traffic, and my server both have the same looking 404 pages.  So to confirm what I was hitting, I added google.com.  ....It is submitting to the URL, but something is 'off' because it's screwing up either c= or key=

Comment: im thinking problem is that i dont actually want to "post" the values to thw url i want (just take values from the form and call url).  im guessing this is different?

Answer (score 0):

when you use `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in `CURL` it will lose cookies if redirect and you don't have any clue of those posting values in next step, just add a new `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` with value of `'-'` which is stdOut and this helps to keep the cookies without even a cookie file, and finally leads you to next step with cookies so next step recognize you as a previous visitor.

```
 curl_setopt ($Curl_Session, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '-');
```

UPDATE:
well if you are redirecting your script to that page, you need to carry the cookies with you when redirect; you have to capture cookies from `CURL` and set them in your script.

```
setcookie('COOKIE NAME FROM CURL RESULT', 'COOKIE VALUE FROM CURL RESULT', 60 * 60 *24 /* YOU CAN EXTRACT FROM CURL COOKIE RESULT */);
header("Location:http://myurl/cgi-bin/thanks.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

So, the USER is doing a POST to your website page and your response is a 301 Moved Permanently http code?

So let’s read The RFC 2616 (about HTTP …)

> 10.3.2 301 Moved Permanently
>
> [...]
>
> If the 301 status code is received in response to a request other than
>   GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect the
>   request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.
>
> Note: When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a
>   301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will erroneously
>   change it into a GET request.

So, the, first time the user is sending the form,doing a POST to:
[your page] After the CURL part, you return a 301 code that will make the browser redirect.
doing a GET to Location: http://myurl.com/cgi-bin/thanks.php.
but this happen only if any off the curl output any code or error.

Make sure the pid is set on the first request, on the post field or, otherwise you will get a PHP NOTICE/WARNING before the redirect. That will make the redirect not work.

Comment your CURL code, and see if your redirect work. If work, means that something BEFORE the redirect code is outputting something on the HTML.